# Unable to access Node.js environment variables in `process.env`

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I got `undefined` when trying to access `process.env` properties using property name. See code example

```
const foo = Object.keys(process.env)[0] // 'node'
console.log(foo === 'node') // true
console.log(process.env.node) // undefined
console.log(process.env['node']) // undefined
console.log(process.env[foo]) // path to node
```

`process.env` contains `node`:

```
{ 
  node: '/Users/jasper.wang/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/node',
  // ...
}
```

For the full output of `process.env` have a look at [this Gist which I made](https://gist.github.com/Emptymu/a47d5afe606e7f12f9c0b141eac28896).

Update:

this is a Webpack issue:

Webpack doesn't recognize extended environment variables so it complied

```
console.log(process.env.extended_variable)
```

to

```
console.log(undefined);
```

Comment: `console.log(process.env.node)`

Comment: @ma_dev_15 That is also `undefined`

Comment: Can you trying consoling `process.env` and share the output?

Comment: Sure, that was too long to put in the description. I created a gist for it
https://gist.github.com/Emptymu/a47d5afe606e7f12f9c0b141eac28896

Comment: I would just like to add: I have tested the above output on Windows 10 with Node.js 12.2.0. I don't have `process.env.node` but I did use `process.env.ALLUSERSPROFILE` for the test. All results did pass though...

Comment: yeah, I think there is something to do with my project setup. I tried in a fresh firebase project and didn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
If you're using Webpack, you can use Webpack [EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/)

In my particular case, I'm also using dotenv and babel. So I fixed it by using [dotenv-webpack](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) and [babel inline dot env plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-dotenv).

Answer (score 0):

```
 plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      process: {
        env: {
          node: JSON.stringify(process.env.node),
        },
      },
    }));
```

In your plugins inside webpack config push these settings as well, it will work for you then.